# Calling webservice on ext prompt

Tags: extjs

I am asking the user for an email, providing the old email.
However, I am not getting the value the user has put in when I break on the webservice that gets called.

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('Email', 'Please confirm your email:', function(btn, text, cfg) {
          if(btn == 'ok' && Ext.isEmpty(text)) {
              var newMsg = '<span style="color:red">Please enter your email:</span>';
              Ext.Msg.show(Ext.apply({}, { msg: newMsg }, cfg));
          }
          else
          { 
              $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/Services/Email.asmx/UpdateEmail",
          data: '{email:"' + email + '"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json"
      });
          }
      }, false, this, email);
```

I think I am not doing it right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `email` that you are trying to post to the webservice does not contain user input. Replace it by `text`:

```
data: '{email:"' + text + '"}',
```

Comment: And that's not valid JSON: property names **must** be enclosed in quotes. You'd better use [`Ext.encode({email: text})`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-encode) or `JSON.stringify({email: text})` to produce it.